# How to intercept not authorazied request to a rest controller (method level authorization) - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

In a REST Controller I have the following method.

```
@GetMapping("/activate_user")
@RolesAllowed({Role.ROLE_ADMIN})
public void activateUser() {
  // Some code here
}
```

If a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` calls this method, it works like it should.
If a user without `ROLE_ADMIN` calls this method, it return an Http-Status 403. That is also ok, but I want now to intercept this call in case the user is not authorized, run some custom code and return some JSON data back to the caller.

I don't know how it could be done with Spring?!

Comment: take a look here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: search about filters. They can intercept the request and you can send back response on failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the accessdenied exception and this way it will only be executed for 403 unauthorized.

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.getWriter().write("Custom Access Denied Message");
}
```

you can use [MVC Interceptor Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc) to intercept specific URLs/APIs

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new ThemeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/adminRole/**");

        registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/auth/*", "/ui/**", "/xyz/**");
    }
}
```

You can even exclude specific URL's.

Comment: If I do that, then I don't Know from which method did this Exception been thrown?! I want to intercept only the AccessDeniedException thrown from this particular method, not intercepting all the AccessDeniedExceptions been thrown. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can intercept only specific URL in that case. I have updated the answer.